# How to select most occurring common values from each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the DafaFrame

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
A     B     C   OP
B     D     A   JK
B     C     E   MK
A     B     B   LO
```

and like get DataFrame below:

```
Result Total
B       5
A       3
C       2
```

I manage to get top values from each column using the following command but not sure how to get from there to the DataFrame needed. Trying to find the best way to approach this scenario.

```
df.groupby(['Col1']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
df.groupby(['Col2']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
df.groupby(['Col3']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack` and `value_counts()`  and then can rename columns

```
 df.stack().value_counts().head(3).to_frame('Total')
```

If you need to filter columns as per your comment.

```
cols=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
df.loc[:,cols].stack().value_counts().head(3).to_frame('Total')
```

Comment: This works great but I have to filter the columns first. Not sure if this is the best way to do it though: 
df.filter(['Col1', 'Col2','Col3'], axis=1).stack().value_counts().head(3).to_frame('Total')

Comment: list columns `cols=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']` and then use the `loc` accessor
`df.loc[:,cols]` See my edits above

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with specify columns in `value_vars` and then counts values by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and last convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.melt(value_vars=['Col1','Col2','Col3'], value_name='Result')
         .groupby(['Result'])
         .size()
         .nlargest(3)
         .reset_index(name='Total'))
print (df1)
  Result  Total
0      B      5
1      A      3
2      C      2
```

Or use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`Series.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html) for top3:

```
df1 = (df.melt(value_vars=['Col1','Col2','Col3'], value_name='Result')['Result']
        .value_counts()
        .head(3)
        .rename_axis('Result')
        .reset_index(name='Total'))
print (df1)
  Result  Total
0      B      5
1      A      3
2      C      2
```